# Detecting session in different domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two asp.net applications.  They are on different domains (i.e., app1.com and app2.com).  If app1.com generates an asp.net sessionId, stores it to a cookie and also saves it to a database accessible by both apps, how do I then detect that the same user is now on app2.com?  Visiting app2.com generates a different sessionId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a different session state mode. You could go with either SQL Server session state or a custom one.

You can read more about them on the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes - I was thinking to use sql server.  But if I go that route, can I leave the current cookie implementation?  Would passing the sessionid via url be more of a security concern than sql server?

Comment: Yes you don't need to set the cookieless mode for SQL.  Here's an article that goes through the basics of setting up SQL Server session state: http://www.itorian.com/2012/09/aspnet-session-states-in-sql-server.html